# Obtaining the compound Simpson's rule from simple SR.

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, riemann-integration, simpsons-rule, truncation-error

in [this book](http://62.182.86.140/main/144000/4b34497d0058506d1dfd0092d1bed726/%28Computer%20science%20and%20applied%20mathematics%29%20Philip%20J.%20Davis%2C%20Philip%20Rabinowitz%20-%20Methods%20of%20numerical%20integration-Academic%20Press%20%281984%29.djvu) or [here](http://library.lol/main/4B34497D0058506D1DFD0092D1BED726) on the page $58$ I was trying to obtain the compound Simpson's rule $(2.2.4)$ from the Simple Simpson's approximation as in $(2.2.2)$.
I understand that the compound rule on $-1,...,1$ is obtained
by the simple rule applied on each interval $-1,...,0$ and $0,...,1$ separately.

To this end I divided the interval like this: $a=x_0<...<x_{2n}=b$
with $x_0=-1=a$, $x_1=0$ and $x_2=1=b$.

Now I was left with these two partial results and got stuck with how to get rid of $f$-values at fractional points. Perhaps some linear transformation would help:

$$\frac{1}{6}(f(-1)+4f(\frac{-1}{2})+f(0))$$ and
$$\frac{1}{6}(f(0)+4f(\frac{1}{2})+f(1))$$

If **somehow adding** these two expressions they should yield
$$\frac{h}{3}(f_0+4f_1+f_2),$$ with $h=1$
but I'm unable to get correctly get rid of fractional values.

Also there is an additional term $2\cdot f(0)=f_2$ while summing up.

[image]

Comment: How did you get the idea that you have to eliminate $f(\pm\frac12)$? Your source does not say it, and the idea in general is that you get a more exact integral approximation by employing more intermediate points. One could employ a higher-order approximation or apply the current approximation to the segments. See Romberg integration, where a table in both these directions is built. Note that there one of the first columns (possibly after the midpoint rule value, or so) is the trapezoidal rule and the next after it its Richardson extrapolation, the Simpson rule.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I need obtain this $$\frac{1}{3}(f_0+4f_1+f_2).$$ Each $f_i$ is and must be a  point from the subdivision of the interval $[a,b]$, in my case $a=-1<0<1=b$ so each point $f_i=f(x_i)$ is a value at an integer point from $-1,0,1$. What's wrong with this reasoning ?

Comment: In every segmentation the function value at the midpoint of each segment is used in the integration. The formula you write is for the segmentation with one segment, where $0$ is the midpoint. Compare with the midpoint rule, 3/8 rule, Gauß-2 rule.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes my formula $\frac{1}{3}(f_0+4f_1+f_2),$ is such that $f_1=f(0)$. But the procedure to obtain it (by virtue of being composite/compound) and this is from the book cited page $70$, is to use simple Simpson's rule on the subintervals $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$. But then there occur a value at $\frac{1}{2}$ so this formula doesn't arise as a such after all. **The citation from the book**: `A compound or composite rule arises when the interval of integration is 
subdivided into a number of equal subintervals and & fixed rule of integration 
is applied to each of the subintervals. `

Comment: Yes, so what? If the subdivision is $-1,-\frac12,0,\frac12,1$, then the composite Simpson rule uses the values there and at additional points $\frac{k}4$, $k=-3,-1,1,3$. Did you comprehend equation 2.2.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation change might be somewhat disorienting.

The point sequence where the function is evaluated is $a=x_0<x_1<x_1<...<x_{2n}=b$, $x_{i+1}=x_i+h$.

The segmentation for the composite Simpson rule are the $n$ segments with borders at $a=x_0,x_2,x_4,...,x_{2n}=b$, this is why the point sequence has $2n+1$ points. The length of the segments is $2h$, thus giving a factor of $\frac{2h}{6}=\frac{h}3$

Thus for 2 segments in $[a,b]=[-1,1]$ you get $x_0=-1$, $x_2=0$, $x_4=1$ with the midpoints $x_1=-\frac12$ and $x_3=\frac12$. There is no contradiction, the resulting formula is simply
$$
\frac{1/2}3(f_0+4f_1+2f_2+4f_3+f_4),~~~f_k=f(x_k).
$$

Comment: Very good. I was trying to obtain $\frac{1}{3}(f_0+4f_1+f_2)$ while the right thing was to obtain the next level $\frac{1/2}3(f_0+4f_1+2f_2+4f_3+f_4)$. Could you kindly explain to me yet where the number $6$ in  $\frac{2h}{6}$ came from ? It is clear to me that $b-a=2h$.

Comment: In the original formula you have $\frac{b-a}6$. In the composite formula you have $a_i=x_{2i}$, $b_i=x_{2i+2}$ for segment $i$, with length $2h$.

Comment: Well, and $1/2$ here $\frac{1/2}3(f_0+4f_1+2f_2+4f_3+f_4)$ ?

Comment: I am following the book where $h$ is the distance between points and not the length of the segments.

Comment: By 3rd line in your answer $x_{i+1}=x_i+h$ so the distance between points is $h$ and not $\frac{h}{2}$. Why do you  suddenly use  $\frac{1/2}{3}$ ?

Comment: Yes, so $2h=1$ is the segment length for each of the two segments.

Comment: Right. As you have explained $\frac{1}{6}$ could you please analogously explain $\frac{3}{8}$ in the Simpson's $3/8$ rule ?

Comment: You compute the interpolation polynomial for the nodes $[0,1/3,2/3,1]$ and integrate it. No extra tricks required.

Comment: I've tried, but I've made something wrong: with the nodes $[0,1/3,2/3,1]$ and values at them respectively $[0,1,2,3]$ I've obtained the polynomial $\frac{x}{3}$ and then integrating it from $0$ to $1$ is $\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: So you know that in the general formula $w_0f(0)+w_1f(1/3)+w_2f(2/3)+w_3f(1)$ you get $w_1+2w_2+3w_3=\frac32$. Now insert the other monomials of low degree and solve the linear system for the weights.

Comment: I'll do it. Could you please give me a hint how have you obtained the r.h.s. $\frac{3}{2}$ ?

Comment: I think I've got it: $\int_0^1 x \ dx=\frac{1}{2}$ ? And the next equation reads $\frac{1}{3}=w_1\frac{1}{9}+w_2\frac{4}{9}+w_3$ is that correct ?

Comment: Finally I've obtained $w_0=\frac{1}{8},w_1=\frac{3}{8},w_2=\frac{3}{8},w_3=\frac{1}{8}$. How do I get from this $$\frac{3h}{8}(f_0+3f_1+3f_2+f_3)$$ ?

Comment: I think you should combine these calculations on the 3/8 method into a new question. Take care of what the actual domains, functions and their values are, you seem to be too fast sometimes. It might happen that no question remains in the end. // The segment in the context of the composite method is $[x_0,x_3]$. As $h$ is the distance in the sequence of all sampling points, the segment length is $3h$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was missing, good now it is $3h$. But it was always the case that $w_0$ disappeared : why is really $w_0=\frac{1}{8}$ ?

Comment: Consider the integral of a constant function.

Comment: Please, how do you know that there is a **unique** solution to the equations $.w.......=\int_0^1 x^k dx$ for $k=0,...,n$ ?

Comment: As long as the solution is not unique you can add another condition for one power higher. Usually you get first the unique solution and then some linear dependent order conditions. But with symmetry you can also get that the odd-power conditions give automatically zero. For instance for the Gauß points you get order $2s$ with $s$ node points, or compare back to the Simpson rule. With random node points you usually get as many order conditions satisfied as there are points.